# constexpr vs repeated function calls performance

Tags: c++, performance, repeat, constexpr

I was testing out the below code to check the performance of `constexpr`. For the first iteration the results are as expected. But for the next iterations, normal function calls outperform `constexpr` sometimes. What am I missing here? I expect `constexpr` call to be better in any case. Also the time taken by the normal function also decreases after first iteration. How can this behavior be explained?

You can see the code results [here](http://tpcg.io/wWHqLD)

> Edit: If I un-comment the lines in the below code providing different values to sum for each iteration, still the results are similar. You can see its results [here](http://tpcg.io/zP0wMg)
>
> Edit2: I tried @geza changes and performed the operation for 3 Million for the first function call and with `3 Million + i` for the second function call. I was expecting the constexpr to take very less time(almost same as the time taken with 100) but its taking as much time as the non-constexpr function. Results [link](http://tpcg.io/cFt0yt)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

constexpr long long sum(const int* n){
    long long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= *n; i++){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

long long sum(int*  n){
    cout<<"Calling sum\n";
    long long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= *n; i++){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}


int main(void){
    const int* p;
    int a = 100;
    p = &a;
    
    int *p1;
    p1 = &a;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        /*
        int* p1;
        int b = 100 + i; //If I uncomment the lines here are remove the 
        p1 = &b;         //earlier p1 declaration. Still the results are similar
        */
    
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
        cout<<sum(p1)<<endl;
        auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout<<"Time taken Non constexpr: "<<duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count()<<endl;
        
        start = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
        cout<<sum(p)<<endl;
        stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout<<"Time taken constexpr: "<<duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count()<<endl;
    }
}
```

My code is simple, create two pointers one is constant (`p`) and other one is not (`p1`). While calling `sum()` with `p1`, the function without `constexpr` gets called, which can be seen by the print **"Calling sum** and while calling with `p`, function with `constexpr` gets called, which can be seen as nothing is printed.

> Results

$g++ -o main *.cpp
$main
Calling sum
5050
Time taken Non constexpr: 63
5050
Time taken constexpr: 7

Calling sum
5050
Time taken Non constexpr: 5
5050
Time taken constexpr: 6
.
.
.
.
**Calling sum

5050

Time taken Non constexpr: 2

5050

Time taken constexpr: 6**
.
.
.
.
Calling sum
5050
Time taken Non constexpr: 2
5050
Time taken constexpr: 2

Comment: `constexpr` is *not* a performance optimization. You use it for things that need/could be done at compile time.

Comment: Caching issues? And for benchmarking always build with optimization enabled. And don't include output to console with your timing.

Comment: How can the results be explained starting from 1st iteration? Since the function with `constexpr` is evaluated during compile time, its value is like a constant during runtime. So isn't it supposed to give better results compared to the other function which is executed every time?

Comment: And you should probably check what the compiler have generated for machine code. Note that the results of your function calls are independent of the timing loop, so the compiler could optimize it to maybe not calculate the result more than once?

Comment: In fact, the compiler would be allowed to fold the result of both function calls, or neither. Nothing here guarantees compile-time execution, and an optimizer is allowed to have the program take any shortcuts that don't change the observable behavior.

Comment: Hmm, I just observed that even If i give different value to the sum function for each iteration, the execution times are more or less similar. Even if I consider that the compiler inlined the non constexpr function, I still can't explain the results.

Comment: If called with something that is not a compile time constant the constexpr function will behave like a non-constexpr one.
Think about it, with a runtime argument you cannot have compile time evaluation.
Also as others commented, the output operation is the dominant part.

Comment: What happens if you make it more of a real test? Say set `a` to around 30,000? And output something to `cout` before the loop in `main`? Then try again after moving all the output lines outside the timed sections.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl.  Whether or not constexpr function was called or not can be determined by the print **Calling sum**. It is working as expected.

Comment: @JaMiT. Will try that out.

Comment: @JaMiT. I tried with 3000000. See [link]( http://tpcg.io/tPuMM9). Still can't explain the results.

Comment: Change the compiler options and add `-O2`. Nobody cares about the performance of unoptimized code.

Comment: @HariUserX just because that function was picked by overload resolution does not mean that it was evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @HariUserX What's left to explain? There are now enough iterations to dwarf the initialization and use of `cout`. The numbers are pretty much the same for the two functions, as expected. (Well, as expected by those who know that `constexpr` should have no impact on performance, at least when not evaluating a constant expression.)

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl. Makes sense now. Seems like the first function was not evaluated during compile time. Thanks.

Comment: On the website you've linked, go to the Project menu, then Compile Options, and add `-O2` to the Compilation Command. You will then see very different run times.

Comment: @Blastfurnace. Awesome, Just as I wanted. Thanks very much. Should have tried out your comment much earlier. Can you add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you enable optimizations and then rerun your benchmark. C++, especially libraries, depends on compiler optimizations to produce fast assembly code. Optimizers can strip away library abstractions and then emit dramatically better code.

The website you linked allows you to change compiler options, just add `-O2` to set optimization level 2 and rerun the benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

Your measurement is wrong. Your timings include printing to `stdout`. Modify your program to correctly measure time (and remove the `cout` from `sum`):

```
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
auto r = sum(p1);
auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
cout<<r<<endl;
cout<<"Time taken Non constexpr: "<<duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count()<<endl;
```

You'll notice that time will be 0 in (almost) all cases.

(An explanation of your original program: it seems, that the first call to `cout <<` takes more time than the other ones. It is likely that `cout` does some kind of postponed initialization, that's why the first call is slower.)

And note, as you don't call `sum(const int *)` in a `constexpr` context, it will be used as a "normal" function call, just like `sum(int *)`.

Comment: I think, its not the `cout<<"Calling sum\n";` in the second function. It looks like `auto r = sum(p1)` and the separately printing `cout<<r<<endl;`. If we do the same thing for the second call, it also gave all zeroes. Now this is more weird. But its good as all are zeroes.

Comment: @HariUserX: maybe it's the `endl`, which does flushing, triggers the slowness (first time only. I mean, the first actual print is slow).

Comment: I tried you changes for 3000000. Again the same results.

Comment: @HariUserX: what do you mean by same results? Note, when measuring time, you need to make sure that the CPU has a constant frequency. It is usual, that it takes a little time for the OS/CPU to increase the clock speed.

Comment: @HariUserX: please read my answer: "And note, as you don't call sum(const int *) in a constexpr context, it will be used as a "normal" function call, just like sum(int *).". That's why there is no difference. And note, if you enable optimization, it is likely that you get the same code for non-constexpr function you'd get for a constexpr function (called in a constexpr context). Enabling optimization is crucial when measuring speed.

Comment: Thanks. I understood.